# Handling Throwable/Error in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Given: we skip the discussion on why handling Error/Throwable is bad.

In spring, I can handle Exception with ExceptionMapper, but there is no ThrowableMapper or ErrrorMapper.

I wonder is there a generic way to handle all Throwable/ Error in Spring?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of spring are you using?  Are you trying to handle errors in Spring MVC or vanilla Spring?  Do you mean the `@ExceptionHandler`?

Comment: Hi @JohnFarrelly , im using spring framework 4.2.3 , the Exceptionhandler can only handle exception , not error or throwable

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if Spring provides a way to handle Error/Throwable but it's not for nothing there is a quote there

> we skip the discussion on why handling Error/Throwable is bad.

In general it is advisable not just in Spring but in Java never to catch Error/Throwable events as they are usually system related and should go to JVM. If you catch them you might interfere with standard JVM behavior. Search and read on the issue, but as a general recommendation don't handle yourself anything higher then Exception (i.e. don't catch Error/Throwable)

Comment: some 3rd party libs can make mistake and throw error instead of exception